# Linux: copy all files using the * wildcard that contain the word file

Tags: linux, wildcard, cp

I've worked all night on this, but haven only solved part of the problem. I am trying to copy all files using the * wildcard that contain the word file in the filename into the work directory.

Comment: This isn't a programming question.

Comment: @meagar It is if you think of sh as a programming language. Sort of.

Comment: @melpomene It *is* a programming language. This still isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try doing this :

```
cp *file* ./work/
```

Comment: That would also try to copy directories containing the word "file" (yielding an warning message under `bash`).  In a good shell like zsh you can use the extended glob option and e.g. `*file*(.)` to specify that only regular files should be matched, but not sure about bash - don't use it myself.

Comment: This allowed me to quickly copy all the ```.less``` files in a directory. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
cp *file* work/
```

Is this homework?